# Comparing Sprites?

Tags: c++, sfml

For a game I'm working on, I'd like to compare two sprites in SFML2, such as with an if() statement. For example, I could have a large 1280x1024 image with one gray pixel among all black pixels. I would then have 2 separate sprites, one is the gray pixel alone, and the other is the map. I would crop only the gray pixel from the map and compare the two, if true, do other things.

Do you see what I'm getting at here? Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing and why, but you don't want to be comparing pixel-to-pixel large sprites. For the purpose of collision detection you should use something smarter and less computationally intensive, e.g. compare object coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im with Alex in saying there are smarter ways to check sprites.

1. Compare the file names not, don't reference a single pixel within an image, because you have to load the entire image into memory to do that atm you are loading 1.3MBytes into memory just to check a single pixel?
2. Store all of your resources in a Resource Manager and reference them via a UID, if a resource has UID then use that resource.

Number 2 is preferable above all else, but there are many other ways

Edit: As per comments, you wouldn't "crop" out the pixel, you would just load image into memory and use the Image class to get the colour of a pixel at a location. The following would be an example

```
sf::Image* map = MapSprite->GetTexture()->CopyToImage()
if (map->GetPixel(666,666) == sf::Color::Black)
{
    //Funky stuff here
}
```

NOTE: You mentioned SFML2 so this is from that set of Documentation, may be different for 1.6

Edit2: Its been a while since I've used SMFL so hopefully the code snippet will at least give you direction

Comment: This doesn't really help me. The 1280x1024 dimensions were an example, further more this is for creating maps.

Comment: Are trying to determine which file to use?

Comment: so are you reading the map image to create objects at certain locations?